# How to customize the popup.pt template from archetypes.referencebrowserwidget?

Tags: plone

How can i customize the popup.pt template from archetypes.referencebrowserwidget in my own package?

Apparently customizing it with z3c.jbot doesn't seem to work.

Thanks !

My z3c.jbot setup (that works just fine for other skin and browser templates):

In the `configure.zcml` of my theme package:

```
<include package="z3c.jbot" file="meta.zcml" />
<browser:jbot directory="jbot_templates" layer=".browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific" />
```

Filename of the template:

```
archetypes.referencebrowserwidget.browser.popup.pt
```

Comment: please, post your jbot configuration and the file name of your custom template (should be something like archetypes.referencebrowserwidget.skins.referencebrowser.referencebrowser.pt).

Comment: z3c.jbot is working here. If you make a different claim then provide evidence.