# How to override popup.pt in Plone?

Tags: overriding, plone, archetypes

I was able to modify the original *popup.pt* and see changes in my instance, but when I try to override it by copying and renaming to `archetypes.referencebrowserwidget.browser.popup.pt` in my theme/(add-in) *overrides* folder I am unable to see my changes.

I overrode the path_bar class viewlet, following this [tutorial](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/customizing-main-template-viewlets/overriding-a-class-viewlet). I attempted to follow the same logic for overriding *popup.pt*, but I was unable to get Plone to see the file in my `configure.zcml`.

**configure.zcml**:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:i18n="http://namespaces.zope.org/i18n"
    xmlns:genericsetup="http://namespaces.zope.org/genericsetup"
    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
    xmlns:plone="http://namespaces.plone.org/plone"
    i18n_domain="mytheme.theme">

    <includeDependencies package="." />

    <plone:static
    directory="resources"
    type="theme"
    />

    <genericsetup:registerProfile
           name="default"
           title="mytheme.theme"
           directory="profiles/default"
           description="Installs the mytheme.theme package"
           provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION"
     />

    <browser:viewlet
         name="plone.path_bar"
         manager="plone.app.layout.viewlets.interfaces.IAboveContent"
         class=".customizations.PathBarViewlet"
         permission="zope2.View"
         layer=".interfaces.IMyTheme"
    />      

   <browser:page
       name="login_main_template"
       for="*"
       permission="zope.Public"
    template="login_main_template.pt"
   />  
</configure>
```

While searching for a solution I found this Stackoverflow question - [How to customize the popup.pt template from archetypes.referencebrowserwidget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299522/how-to-customize-the-popup-pt-template-from-archetypes-referencebrowserwidget). I added/:

```
<include package="z3c.jbot" file="meta.zcml" />
<browser:jbot directory="jbot_templates" layer=".browser.interfaces.IThemeSpecific" />
```

to my `configure.zcml` and removed the `browser:viewlet` from my previous attempt but I was still unable to get Plone to see my overview.

Which method do I need to use to override, the class viewlet, the z3c.jbot, or just the standard copy/rename method? I have read thru the Plone documentation multiple times, but still unable to resolve my issue. If I need to post any additional files please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The z3c.jbot approach usually just works fine. 
You have to be sure, that the file you place into to your `jbot_templates` folder has the right name. 
The path to the popup.pt is `archetypes/referencebrowserwidget/browser/popup.pt`, 
So in your case the filename must be `archetypes.referencebrowserwidget.browser.popup.pt`

Please make sure that your browserlayer `.interfaces.IMyTheme` is active on your site -> `browserlayer.xml`